# does not exists android device monitor in android studio 3.6

Tags: android, monitor

does not exists android device monitor in android studio 3.6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV1a5.jpg)

CAN you help me plz ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device Monitor was deprecated in Android Studio 3.1
Now, in 3.2  you can use the following to do the same tasks
Android Profiler
Android Emulator
Device File Explorer

Check out the official document [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor)